# How to move large number of files files on disk to HDFS sequence files

Tags: apache-camel, hdfs, flume

I want to move large number of small files to HDFS sequence file(s). I have come across two options:

1. Use Flume. Flume does not have a built in file source and this requires a custom source to push the files.
2. Use apache camel file to hdfs route.

Even though the above two methods serve the purpose, I would like to weigh other options available before picking one. In particular i am interested in a solution that is more configurable and results in less maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

> Use Flume. Flume does not have a built in file source and this requires a custom source to push the files.

Umm... no, that's not right. Flume has a [Spooling Directory Source](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source) which would do the high level of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that. I will check it out. I guess, the last time i looked at flume sources was too long ago.

Comment: Looks like this solution is not appropriate for moving very large files as it is not a streaming.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not a streaming'. What did you want it to do that it cannot do?

Comment: Want to move files of size 120gb each.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a few lines of code with Camel. i.e. `from("file:/..").to("hdfs:..")` plus some init and project setup.

Not sure how much easier (less lines of code) you can do it using any method.

If the [HDFS options](http://camel.apache.org/hdfs) in Camel is enough for configuration and flexibility, then I guess this approach is the best. Should take you just a matter of hours (or even minutes) to have some test cases up and running.

Comment: Thanks. camel-hdfs does help in moving the files. Couple of things holding me away from camel-hdfs is the missing support for snappy compression and we could end up in an inconsistent state during abnormal shutdown. I am looking at additional ideas from SO users to weigh the options. I am also looking at a more configurable approach possibly, than code, build, maintain and rebuild so that the analysts and hadoop administrators can handle the task, like the configuration files on flume agents. I am not against building new code if that is a better alternative.